# Comparar valores de dos array PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con `php` y `codeigniter`, y necesito comparar dos `array` del tipo `$array1 = ['1','2','3',].` y sin importar el tamaño de ambos saber los valores que no están presentes en ambos `array`, por ejemplo

```
$array1 = ['1','2','4','5']
$array2 = ['1','2','6']`
```

El resultado que necesito

`['4','5','6']`

Comment: quiero obtener los valores que no estan presentes en ambos array por ejemplo los valores 1 y 2 estan en ambos por eso no se toman en cuenta, los valores 4 y 5 del primer array y el valor 6 del segundo son los valores que deseo que me devuelba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se trata de `PHP` puede emplear dos funciones para este fin , [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php) para encontrar la diferencia entre los `arrays` *(valores del primer array pasado por parámetro que no están en el segundo array pasado por parámetro)* y [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php) para combinar los resultados.

```
/* Obtener los valores que están en $array1 y no en $array2*/
$array1 = ['1','2','4','5'];
$array2 = ['1','2','6'];
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));  /* Result ['4','5']*/

/* Obtener los valores que están en $array2 y no en $array1*/
$array1 = ['1','2','4','5'];
$array2 = ['1','2','6'];
print_r(array_diff($array2, $array1));  /* Result ['6']*/
```

Luego estos dos resultados se combinan haciendo uso de la función `array_merge` , el resultado final sería :

```
$result = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
print_r($result); /*  resultado : ['4','5','6'] */
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio de mnucho